# Certain views loading while others do not on back button press ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have multiple components that link to each other using `Link` and `Redirect`. When I hit the back or forward button to navigate through the views, some of the views don't show up, while some of them do. My landing page component shows up. Here are my routes:

```
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/blades" component = { BladesLanding }/>
                <Route exact path="/blades/create" component = {(props) => <CreateAccount {...props} setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setUser={setUser} setAccess={setAccess} access={access}/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/blades/login" component = {(props) =>  <Login {...props} setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setUser={setUser} setAccess={setAccess} access={access}/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/blades/home" component = {(props) => <BladesHome {...props} setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setUser={setUser} loggedIn={loggedIn} user={user}/>}/> 
                <Route exact path="/blades/newgame" component = {(props) => <NewGame {...props} loggedIn={loggedIn} user={user}/>}/>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Here is the code for my landing page component. This view successfully loads on a back button press:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

let socket;
export default function BladesLanding() {

    return (
        <div>
        <form></form> 
        <Link to={{ pathname: '/blades/create'}}>Create Account</Link>
        <Link to={{ pathname: '/blades/login'}}>Login</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is code for a view that doesn't successfully load on a back button press:

```
import React from 'react';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import { useState } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

export default function Login(props) {
    ...
    return(
        <div>
            <TextField label='username'
                onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            />
            <TextField label='password'
                onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button onClick={submitAccount}>Confirm</Button>
            { props.access ? <Redirect to="/blades/home"/> : <SimpleDialog/>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks

## EDIT

This is additional code that doesn't work on pressing the back button:

```
export default function BladesHome(props) {

   ...

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.user)
    },[])

    return(
        <div>
            {console.log(props.user)}
            <Link to="/blades/newgame">Login</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This will be redirected to /blades/home when you press back button due to the presence of redirect field

Answer (score 1):

There are some improvements you can do in your code and that might solve your problem as well:

1. Render your components as children, rendering components inside of component prop is not recommended:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/blades" component={BladesLanding}/>
    <Route exact path="/blades/create">
      <CreateAccount setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setUser={setUser} setAccess={setAccess} access={access}/>
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/blades/login">
      <Login setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setUser={setUser} setAccess={setAccess} access={access} />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/blades/home">
      <BladesHome setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setUser={setUser} loggedIn={loggedIn} user={user}/>
    </Route> 
    <Route exact path="/blades/newgame">
      <NewGame loggedIn={loggedIn} user={user}/>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

2. You can pass a string directly to `to` prop:

```
<Link to="/blades/create">Create Account</Link>
```

Let me know if it still gives you some problem.

Comment: It didn't change the non-loading issue, but it does make my code look better, so thanks!

Comment: Which components you want to load when you press back and what is the URL when you press it?

Comment: I want to load the `home` component when I press back from the `NewGame` component, and I want the `NewGame` component to load when I press the forward button from the `home` component.

Comment: `{ props.access ? <Redirect to="/blades/home"/> : <SimpleDialog/>}` If it's not redirecting then <SimpleDialog might be covering your screen, that's why you're not seeing rendered components. Maybe try add console.log in your component to see if it is being mounted or not.

Comment: I did a `useEffect` with a `console.log` inside, and added another `console.log` in the return and nothing logs when I back into the page or refresh.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example on codesandbox.

Comment: Here is the sandbox. I can't recreate the issue. I took out all the routes though fo the sandbox since they didn't work. Could they somehow be the issue? I don't see why that would be the case. https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-grothendieck-n0m7x?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I deployed my site (http://mattbraly.biz/blades) and if you go "login" with username 1 password 1, you will be taken to home. After that, click "login" to be taken to the newgame page and then back out, and the component won't load.